# How to make a reliable "dead man's switch" for an automated process?

Tags: automation, monitoring

Case in point: backups of my server. I want to know if backups fail. Typically I get an email if something goes wrong. Unfortunately (and this has happened), there are plenty of reasons that the error reporting would not fire. Thus I will never know that the backup is broken until I need it (too late).

One option is to switch to *success* notifications, but it's both annoying and I am not sure I would readily notice their absence.

So I'm looking for some way to monitor the process (and let me know it's broken) that is as reliable as possible - assuming I use my laptop, am connected to the Internet, and check mail and IM regularly (which is a given).

[EDIT] I'm using the [Ruby backup gem](http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/) for backups, but I'd prefer a more general solution.

Comment: Perhaps you can arrange for success notifications to be sent to a place that is monitored by a script. The script would check that all is well; would send you an email if all is not well; and would send you, say, a weekly summary. If in any doubt, you could check the logs used by the script.

Comment: Which backup software do you use?

Comment: @Burgi the Ruby backup library - I've added a link to the question

Comment: Since Im not familiar with the product, I cant say for sure.  But looking at the website, it has [logging](http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/logging/) capabilities.  I would think you should be able to look for errors and warnings to find failures.

Comment: @Keltari sure, I can manually look for errors. The question is - how to make error discovery automated and as reliable as possible.

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov well, it sounds like you are having errors.  look in the logs for those errors.  write a script or use a log parser to check for those errors.

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov It sounds to me from your question that your backups are failing and you arent getting the proper notification from the backup program.  And you are asking how to work around that problem.  If thats not the case, you should clarify your question.

Comment: You could turn on success AND failure emails. You can then have a script look for occasions when you get either a failure or no email and flag it for you to look at. Beyond that I'm not familiar enough with the software to recommend anything else.